# Merging 2 filter functions with one If Else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried number of different combinations put 2 hours of attempts got me nowhere. How can I merge the 2 filter functions in one `if .. else ..` statement?

```
$('.app-layout .app-co .badge')
  .filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == 'Off'; })
  .addClass('bg-palette-yellow text-palette-dark-gray');

$('.app-layout .app-co .badge')
  .filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == 'On'; })
  .addClass('bg-palette-green text-palette-dark-gray');
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to merge these two statements that hasn't worked?

Comment: `filter` becomes a `each` with a callback that has an if else on the text being 'Off' or 'On' in order to determine which classes to add.  Should be fairly straight forward.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use each function instead of filter to iterate all $('.app-layout .app-co .badge') and add the classes.

```
$('.app-layout .app-co .badge')
.each(function( index, el ){ 
   $self = $(el);
   if( $self.text() == 'Off') ){
      $self.addClass('bg-palette-yellow text-palette-dark-gray');
   }else if( $self.text() == 'On') ){
      $self.addClass('bg-palette-green text-palette-dark-gray');
   }
});
```

Comment: And you have syntax errors with an unopened `)` on the if and else if

Comment: I believe today's browser can handle 3 times of jQuery instantiation. but I'll edit the answer. thanks.

Comment: Its not a question of if the browser can handle it.  Its the D.R.Y principle.  There's no reason to force the browser to repeat the same operation multiple times, when the result is the same.  Caching the result once in a variable and reusing it is general programming best practice.